# Disable the bottom right corner charms bar in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Moving the mouse to the bottom right corner shortcut for minimizing all windows causes a black charms bar pops up and blocks me from clicking on the shortcut.

Attempted solutions include:

1. Adding the following registry keys at:

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUi
   >
   > **DisableCharmsHint** (REG_DWORD, 1),
   >   **DisableTLCorner** (REG_DWORD, 1),
   >   **DisableTRCorner** (REG_DWORD, 1)
2. Changing the "Corner Navigation" properties in the "Navigation" tab of "Taskbar and Navigation properties" to disable:

   > When I point to the upper-right corner, show the charms
   >   When I click the upper-left corner, switch between my recent apps

These ideas came from YouTube videos and tech sites (including Stack Exchange) but it does not stop the bottom right corner from popping up a black bar when the mouse hovers over it.

There is a 3rd party app (Classic Shell) that has this feature so there *has* to be a way but I have not been able to figure it out yet.  Also, Classic Shell is not a viable answer.  Installation of 3rd-party apps in this setting would take jumping through *way* too many hoops.

Comment: According to [this technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dfa779c7-fed6-4f82-bc00-7b6416c554e2/disable-charms-bar-completely?forum=w8itprogeneral) it can not be done. But I'll keep an eye here if a solution is found...